# Could not run Ec2-server on port 80

Tags: python, django, linux, amazon-ec2, centos

I could run the server on port `8000` but when i try to use `80` with 
`python manage.py runserver myip:80` I get:

> You don't have permission to access that port.

If I use `sudo python manage.py runserver myip:80` I get:

```
File "manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I write `python` in the console I get version `3.5.5` and my `env` is activated.

EDIT:

Using `sudo python3 manage.py runserver myip:80` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Comment: Why would you run that via `yum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here. First of all, only privileged users (e.g. `root` or other users via `sudo`) can bind to ports under 1024.

But more importantly, [`manage.py runserver` should never be used in production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver):

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

I *strongly* advise you to set up a proper web server instead. If you search for "EC2 Django" you'll find plenty of walkthroughs on how to do this properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informations. I only need this server to use some API for some application. And i have only one HTML page to send some POST request to the server. You still think that i have to setup other way or could be ok for my purpose?

Comment: I would still set up a proper web server.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this because you aren't using Python 3. The easiest way to fix this is to create a virtualenv that uses python3 as it's python executable.

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3 envname
workon envname
pip install django
pip install your_other_dependencies
```

Still, as others have said, running the Django webserver in a production environment is dicey at best, and spending some time setting up a Gunicorn/Nginx (or appropriate substitute) will pay dividends long term.